# How to implement stories progress view in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to know to the best way in order to develop a `widget/view` which can work as **instagram, snapchat stories** which illustrated in image below. There are many depndencies for android, but can't find any for flutter.
 I'm thinking to use `carousal/viewpager` to move between stories of different users, but I'm unable to get how to move backward and forward in between stories of single user(either image or video) with progress bar on top of it which will move automatically to next when progress bar completes.
[image]

Comment: could you implementing that or can you find any library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question has been asked for a long time, but for those who still ask the same question, you can use this library: https://pub.dev/packages/story_view or look at it's source to implement the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a custom [ViewPager](http://developine.com/flutter-pageview-viewpager-uiscrollview-with-circular-dots-tutorial/) perhaps using [`Stack`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) + [`Transform`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Transform-class.html) and use [`GestureDetector`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) to switch between pages/stories.

Comment: how will you plase explain ?

Comment: Hey, @RahulKushwaha did you try this: https://pub.dev/packages/story_view ?

Comment: Gargs... .I have tried it . But using this ,I able to implement images as Story Items.  But my requirement is to chage as different views as Story items...How can i impkement it?

Comment: Hey, try posting a question so that I or fellow developers can answer it properly :)

Comment: Thanks. I have asked here.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66422001/change-story-items-as-dynamic-widgets-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you also want to give the user a chance to manually switch to the next image.

Here are some basic ingredients you want to use for an animated "story":

- `AnimationController` with duration depending on the number of images in the story. Start the animation to go through the images and to animate the progress bar. The animation controller usually has a range from 0.0 to 1.0. Let's say you have 5 images. You would display the first image from 0.0 to 0.2, the second image from 0.2 to 0.4...
- `AnimatedBuilder` that listens to the animation controller. The content inside the animation builder will be rebuilt every frame while the animation runs. Inside of the `builder`, calculate which image must be shown.
- `CustomPaint` to manually draw a progress bar with sections for the single image. Pass the current animation value and the number of images to your `CustomPainter`.
- `Image` widget to draw the image.