# change story items as dynamic widgets in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to implement story items as different widgets. Like in this example:

[image: pic]

In this picture, only images are changed, but I want to change as whole widgets as story items.

I have tried the [story_view package](https://pub.dev/packages/story_view). But, in this package, only images and videos can be added. Is there any other library for that?

Comment: Ahhh I get your question now... you should have explicitly mentioned Instagram Stories instead of just Stories.... give me some time, I'll post my answer :)

Comment: Thanks. I will wait ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained by https://stackoverflow.com/users/8164116/daksh-gargas, story view can be easily implemented using stack pageview and a simple gesture detector.

Made a simple story view -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomStoryView extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _CustomStoryViewState createState() => _CustomStoryViewState();
}

class _CustomStoryViewState extends State<CustomStoryView> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final List _colorsList = [Colors.blue, Colors.red, Colors.green, Colors.yellow, Colors.grey, Colors.brown];
  final PageController _controller = PageController();
  double _progressIndicators;
  int _page = 0;
  AnimationController _animationController;
  bool dragEnded = true;
  Size _pageSize;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 2));
    _animationController.addListener(animationListener);
    _animationController.forward();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      _pageSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
      _progressIndicators = (_pageSize.width - 100) / 6;
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          PageView.builder(
            controller: _controller,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (context, index)=>GestureDetector(
              onLongPressStart: _onLongPressStart,
              onLongPressEnd: _onLongPressEnd,
              onHorizontalDragEnd: _onHorizontalDragEnd,
              onHorizontalDragStart: _onHorizontalDragStart,
              onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onHorizontalDragUpdate,
              onTapUp: _onTapDown,
              child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: _colorsList[index],
                child: Center(child: InkWell(
                    onTap: (){
                      print("thiswasclicked $index");
                    },
                    child: Text("Somee random text", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 36),)),),
          ),
            ),
          itemCount: _colorsList.length,
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 48,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: ([0,1,2,3,4,5].map((e) =>
              (e == _page) ? Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: _progressIndicators,
                    height: 8 ,
                    color: Colors.black54,
                  ),
                  AnimatedBuilder(
                    animation: _animationController,
                    builder: (ctx, widget){
                      return AnimatedContainer(
                        width: _progressIndicators * _animationController.value,
                        height: 8 ,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                      );
                    },

                  ),
                ],
              ): Container(
                width: _progressIndicators,
                height: 8 ,
                color: (_page >= e) ? Colors.white : Colors.black54,
              )).toList()),
            ),)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  animationListener(){
    if(_animationController.value == 1){
      _moveForward();
    }
  }

  _moveBackward(){
   if(_controller.page != 0){
     setState(() {
       _page = (_controller.page - 1).toInt();
       _page = (_page < 0) ? 0 : _page;
       _controller.animateToPage(_page, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100), curve: Curves.easeIn);
       _animationController.reset();
       _animationController.forward();
     });
   }
  }

  _moveForward(){
   if(_controller.page != (_colorsList.length - 1)){
     setState(() {
       _page = (_controller.page + 1).toInt();
       _controller.animateToPage(_page, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100), curve: Curves.easeIn);
       _animationController.reset();
       _animationController.forward();
     });
   }
  }
  _onTapDown(TapUpDetails details) {
    var x = details.globalPosition.dx;
    (x < _pageSize.width / 2) ? _moveBackward() : _moveForward();
  }

  _onHorizontalDragUpdate(d){
    if (!dragEnded) {
      dragEnded = true;
      if (d.delta.dx < -5) {
        _moveForward();
      } else if (d.delta.dx > 5) {
        _moveBackward();
      }
    }
  }
  _onHorizontalDragStart(d) {
    dragEnded = false;
  }

  _onHorizontalDragEnd(d) {
  dragEnded = true;
  }

  _onLongPressEnd(_){
  _animationController.forward();
  }

  _onLongPressStart(_){
  _animationController.stop();
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for share this code, it's perfect

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily achieved with [Stack](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html), [Container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html), and a [GestureDetector](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) to switch between pages/stories.

Why [Stacks](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)?

> Flutter's `Stack` is useful if you want to **overlap** several
> children in a simple way, for example, having some text and an image,
> overlaid with a gradient and a button attached to the bottom.

To handle your "fixed" views, which are, in this case:

1. Top Progress bar... you can create your custom progress bar if you want.
2. That image and the user name...

Let's call them `myTopFixedWidgets()`

`Row(children: [CircleAvatar(...),Column(children: [Text(...),Text(...)],)],)`

Now, put your `Widget` that you want to display and that changes (your "story") as the first item of the `Stacks` and place the Widgets 1. and 2. (mentioned above) in the second item of the list.

Maintain a variable `index` to choose the widget that you want to display.

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    widgetsToShowAsAStory[index],
    myTopFixedWidgets() //mentioned above
  ],
)
```

Wrap it inside [GestureDetector](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)

```
List<Widget> widgetsToShowAsAStory = [];

var index = 0;
....
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () { 
    //If the tap is on the LEFT side of the screen then decrement the value of the index
    index-= 1;  //(check for negatives)

    //If the tap is on the RIGHT side of the screen then increment the value of the index 
    index+= 1;  //(check for the size of list)

    //call 
    setState() {}
  },
  child: Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    widgetsToShowAsAStory[index],
    myTopFixedWidgets()
  ],
),)
```

and boom, you're good to go!

Comment: I will try it and let you know if any issues occurs..

Comment: what should i pass in setstate()

Comment: Please read the documentation of how to call this function... it depends on your code flow!

Answer (score 0):

I found solutions from  the story_view. But it doesnot match my requirement. We can only show different widgets as stories items in story_view.We can't perform any actions on widgets. To implement this story_view and to show  different widgets as stories.  Do like this.

First import **story_view** flutter dependencies from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/story_view).

Then import this in main.dart file.

```
import "package:story_view/story_view.dart"; 

                 StoryView(
                        controller: controller,
                        storyItems: [
                          StoryItem.inlineImage(
                            url:
                                "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1536063211352-0b94219f6212?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8YmVhdXRpZnVsJTIwZ2lybHxlbnwwfHwwfA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
                            controller: controller,
                          ),
                          StoryItem(
                              new Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                                    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                                    mainAxisSpacing: 12,
                                    itemCount: imageList.length,
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      return Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: Colors.transparent,
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                                Radius.circular(15))),
                                        child: ClipRRect(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(15)),
                                          child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                                            placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                                            image: imageList[index],
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                    staggeredTileBuilder: (index) {
                                      return StaggeredTile.count(
                                          1, index.isEven ? 1.2 : 1.8);
                                    }),
                              ),
                              duration: aLongWeekend,
                              shown: true),

                          StoryItem(
                              new Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                                    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                                    mainAxisSpacing: 12,
                                    itemCount: imageList.length,
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      return Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: Colors.transparent,
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                                Radius.circular(15))),
                                        child: ClipRRect(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(15)),
                                          child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                                            placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                                            image: imageList[index],
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                    staggeredTileBuilder: (index) {
                                      return StaggeredTile.count(
                                          1, index.isEven ? 1.2 : 1.8);
                                    }),
                              ),
                              duration: aLongWeekend,
                              shown: true),
                        ],
                        onStoryShow: (s) {
                          print("Showing a story");
                        },
                        onComplete: () {
                          print("Completed a cycle");
                        },
                        progressPosition: ProgressPosition.top,
                        repeat: false,
                        inline: false,
                      ),
```